# Overloads and Callbacks on TypeScript

Tags: typescript, callback, operator-overloading

I'm trying to use builder pattern, and have functions that support optional parameters as parameters.
And use something like this:

```
new Service().OnAction(Actions.Add, () => { alert(1); })
    .OnAction(Actions.Substract, () => { alert(1); })
    .ServiceBuilder(serviceOptions);

new Service().OnAction(Actions.Add, (vm, container) => { 
        vm.FirstName = container.find("data-id=FirstName").val();
        vm.LastName = container.find("data-id=LastName").val();
    })
    .OnAction(Actions.Substract, (vm, container) => { alert(1); })
    .ServiceBuilder(serviceOptions);
```

This is what I've tried besides other things

```
public OnAction(actions: Actions, x: (y?:any, z?:any) => void) {
    if (y != undefined && z != undefined) {
        x(y, z);
    }
    else
        x();

    return this;
}
```

I've also checked this link: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html

Comment: And what does not work ? Or what would you like it to do and it does not ?

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Thank you for your interest. I would like to have a functional OnAction, to actually run the functions that i pass as parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want that you method `OnAction` has optional parameters, than you will have to extract the logic that checks undefined to method you are passing to `x`.

Something like this:

```
public OnAction(actions: Actions, x: (y?:any, z?:any) => void) {
    x(y, z);
    return this;
}

new Service().OnAction(Actions.Add, (vm, container) => {
    if (vm === undefined && container === undefined) {
        //some logic if undefined
        return;
    }

    vm.FirstName = container.find("data-id=FirstName").val();
    vm.LastName = container.find("data-id=LastName").val();
})
```

Because in your case it doesn't matter if you call method `x` like

```
x();
```

or like:
    x(y, z);
If `y` and `z` are undefined then it is the same.

Answer (score 1):

At runtime you can't really distinguish between function signatures. `Function` has as [`length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length) property, that can determine the number of parameters of a function and you can use that to distinguish between functions with different number of arguments, but be aware that there is a bug around the `length` property and optional parameters when transpiling to `ES5`.

The point however is that is should not matter if the function accepts the parameters or not, you can just pass all the supported parameters and if the function uses them that is fine, and if it does not that is also fine, no harm done:

```
class MyClass {

    public OnAction(actions: Actions, x: (y?:any, z?:any) => void) {
        // We pass both arguments
        // argument values are null for demo, you can replace with actual parameters 
        x(null, null); 
     }
}

new MyClass().OnAction(Actions.add, ()=> {})// fine arguments passed but unused
new MyClass().OnAction(Actions.add, (vm)=> { console.log(vm) })// one argument used
new MyClass().OnAction(Actions.add, (vm, c)=> { console.log(vm);  console.log(c)})// both argument used
```